# Python substitute sys.stdout causes mypy error

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, mypy

I have the following class:

```
class Unbuffered:
    def __init__(self, stream, logfile):
        self.stream = stream
        self.logfile = logfile

    def write(self, data):
        if self.stream is not None:
            self.stream.write(data)
            self.stream.flush()
        # Write the data of stdout here to a text file as well
        if not self.logfile.closed:
            self.logfile.write(data)
            self.logfile.write("\n")

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

and the following sentence:

`sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout, logfile)`

The problem is that linter **mypy** marks this error in the latest:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Unbuffered", variable has type "TextIO")`

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)

Comment: You see this error, because `Unbuffered` class is not a subclass of `TextIO`. You can inherit from some IO class to avoid it. For example, inheriting `io.TextIOWrapper` works well.